# Unit test a function that ends the promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js

Let's say I have a function in a class named UserController that does something along those lines (where `userService.createUser()` returns a promise):

```
function createUser(req, res)
{
  const userInfo = req.body;

  userService.createUser(userInfo)
    .then(function(){res.json({message: "User added successfully"})})
    .fail(function(error){res.send(error)})
    .done();
}
```

How can I test that, when the promise resolves, `res.json()` is called, and when the promise rejects, `res.send(error)` is called?

I have tried writing a test like this:

```
const userService = ...
const userController = new UserController(userService);
const response = {send: sinon.stub()};

...

const anError = new Error();
userService.createUser = sinon.stub().returns(Q.reject(anError));

userController.createUser(request, response);

expect(response.send).to.be.calledWith(anError);
```

But the test fails with "response.send is never called". I also tried logging something before calling `res.send(error)` and the logging does happen.

My guess is that `expect()` is called before `res.send(error)` is executed since it's asynchronous.

I'm fairly new with promises and unit tests, is it something with my architecture or my use of promises?

I'm using Q for promises and mocha, chai, sinon for my unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have an asynchronous call the `expect` statement is called right after `userController.createUser()` line. So when the assertion is evaluated it has not been called yet.

To test your code asynchronously you will need to declare `done` on your `it` statement and then call it manually to get the result.

**On your test file:**

```
it('should work', function(done) {
  ...
  userController.createUser(request, response);

  process.nextTick(function(){
    expect(response.send).to.be.calledWith(anError);
    done();
  });
});
```

This will make Mocha (I'm assuming you are using it) evaluate your `excpect` just when `done()` is called.

Alternatively you could set a cb function on your `UserController.createUser` function and call it on `.done()`:

**UserController**

```
function createUser(req, res, cb) {
  const userInfo = req.body;

  userService.createUser(userInfo)
    .then(function(){res.json({message: "User added successfully"})})
    .fail(function(error){res.send(error)})
    .done(function(){ if(cb) cb() });
  }
```

And then on your test:

```
userController.createUser(request, response, function() {
  expect(response.send).to.be.calledWith(anError);
  done();
});
```

Comment: Using `process.nextTick` with `done()` did the work ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The easier way, assuming you use Mocha or Jasmine as the framework, is to go ahead as you first started, but just skip Sinon completely (as it is not needed here, unless you test for actual arguments received):

```
// observe the `done` callback - calling it signals success
it('should call send on successful service calls', (done) => {
  // assuming  same code as in question
  ... 

  const response = {send: done};
  userController.createUser(request, response);
});


// observe the `done` callback - calling it signals success
it('should call send on failing service calls', (done) => {
  // assuming  same code as in question
  ... 

  const response = {send: err => err? done(): done(new Error("No error received"))};
  userController.createUser(request, response);
});
```

Disclosure: I am part of the Sinon maintainer team.